# I don't know how to define a variable for bubbleSort java

Tags: java, arrays, mean, bubble-sort, median

I am making a porgram that calculates the Mean(return as double), Median(return as double), Mode(return as int), and Standard deviation of an array that I chose myself. The most helpful things I can find are codes where the array is an input by the user.

I have been using this and some other ones similar as kind of [this guide](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs302-5/resources/examples/MeanMedianMode_Methods.java) as well as my book and notes from class. Some things I just keep tinkering with them until they somehow work.

But like I said, in my code I would just like to put the array in myself and not gather input from the user. I am stuck on the median. I have it all typed up but the compiler is throwing back 1 error that says:

*1 error found:
File: C:\Users\Cori\Desktop\Statistics.java  [line: 41]
Error: The method bubbleSort(int[]) is undefined for the type Statistics*

I did the bubbleSort exactly like the link says and I have been trying all kinds of crazy stuff. I think maybe It has something to do with the variable not being defined, but I really don't know because this is all very foreign to me. Here is my entire code so far. I feel like if I can just figure this out the rest of my project will be very easy.

```
  public class Statistics {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = { 22, 44, 66, 55, 33 };

        double mean;
        double median;
        median = calcMed(a);
        mean = calcMean(a);
        System.out.println("Median:" + median);
        System.out.println("Mean:" + mean);
    }

    public static double calcMean(int[] a) {
        // int[]array = {22,44,66,55,33};
        int i;// =0;
        int sum = 0;
        double mean = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
            sum = sum + a[i];
        }
        {
            mean = ((double) sum / ((double) a.length));
            System.out.println();
        }
        {
            return mean;
        }
    }

    // Calulate median
    public static double calcMed(int[] a) {
        int i;
        int sum = 0;
        int[] sortedArr = bubbleSort(a);

        double median = 0;
        {
            int index = (sortedArr.length - 1) / 2;
            median = sortedArr[index];
        }
        for (int v : sortedArr) {
            System.out.println(v);
        }
        return median;
    }
}
```

Please don't dog my formatting(just some tips would be nice). I just need to know how to fix the bubbleSort so I can calculate the median. Also I know some things are unnecessary, so if you could also give me some pointers on what is ok to delete and things that might be easier.

I figured it out.

Comment: Where is **your** `bubbleSort()` method?

Comment: There must be a **bubblesort** method defintion in your code

Comment: Like the others have stated, you need to include your bubbleSort method.  Your error message is stating that the method named bubbleSort is undefined, not a variable.  Bubble sort isn't something that Java does for you automatically, you must write the method.  Please add your bubbleSort code so that we can help you out.  Also, if you find examples that require user input, you can still use those.  Just remove the user input lines and pass your created array into the method as a parameter.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't even know what that is. I need some major help. So I do the bubbleSort() independent of the median method?

Comment: You need to use `bubbleSort()` method in `calcMed()` method. Sp the `calcMed()` depends on `bubbleSort()`

Comment: So it's `public static double bubbleSort(int[] a)`
 then after it throws back the sorted array how do I use that to calculate the median?

Comment: When you have the sorted array, the median in on the middle index of array

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `bubbleSort` method (copied from the link in question):

```
/**
 * This program returns a sorted version of the input array.
 * 
 * @param arr
 * @return
 */
public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] arr)
{
    // We must sort the array.  We will use an algorithm called Bubble Sort.
    boolean performedSwap = true;
    int tempValue = 0;

    // If we performed a swap at some point in an iteration, this means that array
    // wasn't sorted and we need to perform another iteration
    while(performedSwap)
    {
        performedSwap = false;

        // Iterate through the array, swapping pairs that are out of order.
        // If we performed a swap, we set the "performedSwap" flag to true
        for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i+1])
            {
                tempValue = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1] = tempValue;

                performedSwap = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Without this method you can't sort the array (there are more better solutions then bubblesort, but for this case ok).
The error:

> 1 error found: File: C:\Users\Cori\Desktop\Statistics.java [line: 41]
>   Error: The method bubbleSort(int[]) is undefined for the type
>   Statistics

Tells you there is missing method `bubbleSort()` with parameter `int[]`